# CompileDebugJavawithJavac

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an app which has a fingerprint security before getting to the actual webview.
I keep getting the error `compileDebugjavawithjavac`
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEET7.png]
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEET7.png)

Comment: Please copy the code as text instead of adding a screen shot. Second, with a username like yours, you might want to hide your name in the package and import statements the next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

In line 22 you have unnecessary public declaration.
Delete line 22: `public` to `{`. The `package` statement is needed.

I recommend reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: Might not be unnecessary, as the screenshot could also show an inner class. In that case, the package and import statements have to be removed/moved. Here, it looks like everything between `WebView1` and `extends Activity` should be removed.